# Can't scroll to the left on the webpage

Tags: html, scroll, zooming

people! I have a problem with scrolling in a webpage, that I made. When zoomed you can only scroll to the right and the elements on the left can't be reached. I read that it can be related to absolute positioned elements, but I'm just stuck and can't make it work. I'm begging you for help, someone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try make a div all around the content, and then add a " overflow: auto; " on it in css.

If that does not work, try define a width.

EDIT:

Following your code in codepen, it seems like transform: translate(-50%); is causing your problem, I suggest you use margin: 0 auto; to center your content, if that is what you are trying to.

Comment: I have a wrapper around the content and it has width. Even when I wrote overflow: auto nothing happens.

Comment: With the webpage? Yes, I can

Comment: http://codepen.io/Scribble/pen/KwjxBK This is the link to the codepen. The most of the things are images, that you can not see, but the problem with the scrolling can be noticed. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @Sharen_charshaf It seems like you forgot a <html> and <body> on top of your code, what kind of editor are you using?

Comment: in codepen.io you write only the content in the body. Head, html and doctype aren't being written. But have you found what causes this problem?

Comment: @Sharen_charshaf I downloaded your code, I do not have any problems with the vertical scroll bar on google chrome.

Comment: It's the horizontal scroll bar

Comment: @Sharen_charshaf Try look at this screen share: https://join.me/840-024-879 i can't see any problems with the horizontal scrollbar either.