# Unable to scroll left on my webpage when its size is bigger the device(or window) that has it open

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, scroll

My webpage is hosted on github pages. And it works fine when its on a big screen. However, whenever I and my friends open the page on a device or window that's smaller than the webpage, the option to scroll to the left doesn't exist. In contrast, it's available to scroll right(to the image's right end). How can I solve this problem? And what causes this error?

This is the link to my github repo: https: https://github.com/vroomeee/miniblog
And this is the link to my actual webpage: https://vroomeee.github.io/miniblog

I have searched for similar problems on google, but the closest thing I found was:
[Can't scroll to the left on the webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29582052/cant-scroll-to-the-left-on-the-webpage).
However it still remains unanswered.

I tried overflow: auto; and margin: 0 auto; with div, but all of them don't seem to work.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.7, maximum-scale=0.7"> 
    <title>In the memory of vroomeee</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Vroomeee pictures</h1>
        <img src="1.JPG" alt="a picture of vroomeee">
        <br>
        <button>get next photo</button>
        <p>부름이 보고 싶다ㅎㅎ</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my css file:

```
h1{
color: purple;
font-weight: 1;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-top: 5px solid;
font-size: 75px;
margin: 40px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}


body {
    background-color: salmon;
    color: purple;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

img {
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 0%;
}

button {
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    background-color: salmon;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid #2E1263;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    color: purple;
}

button:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    transition: 0.4s;
    background-color: purple;
    color: salmon;
}

#container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
    height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: Please extract just enough code to create a runnable snippet which you can put into your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I edited my question so that it includes my code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a min-width of your image's general dimensions to its container or body? Though I'm not sure why you'd want horizontal scrolling at all. Maybe add a max-width:100vw to the image?

Comment: The image's left end doesn't show on small devices so I wanted to scroll left. And thanks! I'll try it out!